# Is this SQL Statement Safe for Concurrent Access?

Tags: sql, sql-server, concurrency, transactions, sql-server-2012

Is the SQL statement below 'safe' for concurrent access? At what point will `A` get locked? If it's just before the `INSERT` is there a chance that the first `@count` may be wrong?

```
BEGIN TRAN;
    SELECT @count = count(1) from A
    DELETE FROM A where x=z
    SELECT @newCount = count(1) from A
    SELECT @newCount - @count
COMMIT TRAN;
```

Comment: This is a contrived example. I know I could use @@ROWCOUNT

Comment: Depends on the RDMBs.

Comment: It's sql-server (in this case 2012)

Comment: Now it depends on the isolation level.

Comment: The `DELETE` will place **exclusive locks** on those rows that are being deleted - those that match the criteria `WHERE x=z`. This lock will be held *until the transaction commits* (or rolls back) - and since those are exclusively locks, the following `SELECT @newCount` could run into a lock situation, unless the `COUNT` can be determined on a separate index (on a non-nullable column)

Comment: Really? The `SELECT` can be affected by the operation that locks - even if it's in the same transaction? That's quite counter intuitive to transactions... (to me anyway)

Comment: @usr it would be helpful to know how the isolation level would affect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BEGIN TRAN;
    DECLARE @RC INT
    EXEC @RC = sp_getapplock @Resource='ArchiveLock', @LockMode='Exclusive',  @LockOwner='Transaction', @LockTimeout=15000
    SELECT @count = count(1) from A
    DELETE FROM A where x=z
    SELECT @newCount = count(1) from A
    SELECT @newCount - @count
COMMIT TRAN;
```

Try this. I used this recently to handle set of Delet statements which are called by multiple processes in parallel. The sp_getapplock creates a lock until the transaction is committed which makes other process to wait.

Hope this helps!